# Actualización del tamaño de la pantalla con Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, responsive, game

Tengo un elemento que, por defecto, se adapta al 100% del tamaño de la pantalla (tanto width como height)

```
const screenWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth
const screenHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight

canvas.width =  screenWidth
canvas.height = screenHeight
```

En un principio carga bien y ocupa toda la pantalla correctamente, sin problemas. El problema es el siguiente.

Cuando pongo alejo la vista de la página al 75%

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQWYX.png

Y eso ES lo que quiero.

Pero cuando actualizo,la vista alejada (75%) de la web SE MANTIENE y a la vez mi elemento se estira y CUBRE el espacio entero, lo que hace que al volver al tamaño original de la página (100%) se vea más grande. Hay alguna forma de hacer, que al refrescar la página, se ponga a 100% por defecto?

O que mi elemento mantenga el tamaño que ocupa de normal ( 100%) una vez actualice la página

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podríás probar con algo como

```
tasaAjuste = document.body.width / window.innerWidth
```

Para ver si te da algo diferente a 1 y ahí sabes si hay zoom in o zoom out (y ajustar).